# Silverlight- WCF RIA Services - DataForm + Overriding Add Operation

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Is there a way to have collection of objects which do not have a parameter less constructor and still be able to have the "Add" functionality of Silverlight dataform working.

In my case, I have a class for e.g. **Customer** and it **does not have a parameterless constructor**.

When a collection of this class (ObservableCollection) is data bound to a silverlight DataForm, "Add" button gets disabled as the Customer class does not have a parameterless constructor.

I cannot have a parameterless constructor for this class as it has dependencies that are injected from outside that are required on instantiation.

```
 <toolkit:DataForm  AutoGenerateFields="False" AutoCommit="True" CommandButtonsVisibility="All"  CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                          ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersCollection}" />
```

Are there any solutions/work-arounds to get this working?

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, the parematerless contructor is required for the Add button to get enabled.

A possible alternative of getting the dependencies injected would be to use property injection rather than constructor injection through a DI container. (Haven't tried it though, but I presume it would work. )